# margin right not taking in smaller screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to give the margin right for the text field for iphone screens.....
but i am not able to do it...
i gave in media queries by creating an id....
its taking the border color but its not talking the margin property....
providing my code below.....
when u reduce the browser window u can find it....

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/U4ygP/1/ i have tidy up the code...and the code is found in the line number 4507

```
@media(max-width:768px)
{
.page-content
{
    background:transparent
}
.page-content .page
{
    margin-top:40px
}


#nameForm{ border: 1px solid red;  margin-right: 12px; width: 354px;}
#inquiryForm{ border: 1px solid red; margin-right: 12px;  width: 354px;}
```

Comment: If you hit the TidyUp button you'll get nicer code and some helpful hints on how to properly set up a fiddle. It's hard to do any troubleshooting with it the way you have it.

Comment: Second the motion - please come up with an easier test case rather than just dumping your page into a fiddle and asking others to debug your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/U4ygP/1/ i have tidy up the code...and the code is found in the line number 4507

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your media query needs adjusting:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    }
```

I added

```
#nameForm {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: 12px;
        min-height: 30px;
        width: 364px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    #inquiryForm {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin-right: 12px;
        width: 364px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-left: 12px;
    }
```

Comment: not really sure what your trying to achieve but i have updated the fiddle see here http://jsfiddle.net/Jrand/U4ygP/3/

Comment: yeah it works fine...can you tell me what line of the code did u make the changes.....